# Allow cross-origin for X-Frame-Options

Tags: blogger, iframe

I get this error message in my console when loading a widget displaying ads on my Blogger blog:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: <ext-url> does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

How can I allow cross-origin framing in Blogger?